# How can I set a value using scanf in a nested struct in c without ->?

Tags: c, struct

I can't specify correctly the address of the variable cociente in scanf, I have been trying to obtain the memory address and i can't I hope you can help me.
I am using 2 structs, both of them are dynamically allocated. These are the pieces of code that can clarify this.

```
typedef struct termino
{
  int exponente;
  float cociente;
} termino;

typedef struct polinomio
{
  //Se tiene un conjunto de términos de nombre polinomio
  termino* polinomio;
  int size;
} polinomio;

  polinomio* polinomio_;
  termino* terminos;
  for (i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
    printf("Ingrese el cociente %d:\n",i);
    scanf("%f",&((*polinomio_).(polinomio+i).cociente));
    //printf("\n%.2f",(*(polinomio_).*(polinomio+i).cociente);
  }
```

I get the error using gcc:

```
main.c:37:32: error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token
     scanf("%f",&((*polinomio_).(polinomio+i).cociente));
                                ^
```

Comment: The dot notation signifies a field within a structure. `polinomio+i` is not such a field.

Comment: try `scanf("%f",&(((polinomio_->polinomio)+i)->cociente));`

Comment: it still throws error

Comment: Array notation would be a lot easier to understand.

Comment: I will follow your advices Fiddling Bits,  thanks to all :)

Comment: Try this: `scanf("%f",&polinomio_->polinomio[i].cociente);`

Comment: yep. And the array notation: `scanf("%f",&((polinomio_->polinomio[i]).cociente));`. Please post the exact error if it doesn't work for you (it works for me).

Comment: Using the array notation you both shared it worked, thanks

Comment: You need to allocate space for `polinomio_` and `polinomio_->polinomio` to point to, before doing this

Comment: I didn't paste all the code, I just pasted parts. For future times I will consider pasting more adequate lines for a better understanding of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a "+i", be carefull of the parenthesis, without "`->`":

```
scanf("%f",&( (* (((*polinomio_).polinomio)+i) ).cociente) );
```

and with "`->`":

```
scanf("%f",&( ( (polinomio_->polinomio)+i )->cociente) );
```

But it is probably better to use table index, as suggested in the comments, but you asked without operator "`->`":

```
scanf("%f",&( ((*polinomio_).polinomio)[i].cociente) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is the least of your worries, `polinomio_` is not initialized so the `scanf` will put some values in the memory somewhere potentially causing a crash

```
polinomio* polinomio_;  <-- not initialized
for (i = 0; i < size_; i++) {
  printf("Ingrese el cociente %d:\n",i);
  scanf("%f",&((*polinomio_).(polinomio+i).cociente));  <-- deref
}
```

instead first let polinomio_ point to allocated struct

```
polinomio_ = malloc(sizeof(struct polinomio));
```

inside the struct you have another pointer (polinomio), you need to allocate to what that points to as well.

```
polinomio_.polinomio = malloc(sizeof(struct termino)* size_);
```

once you have done that you can fill your structure

```
scanf( "%f", &(polinomio_->polinomio[i].cociente) );
```

Try to use English variable names and types, at least when you post here in SO but in general it is better if you ever want to publish your code somewhere. Another tip is to capitalize the types, that way it makes it a bit easier to see what is a type and what is an instance of the type/pointer.

e.g.

```
typedef struct termino
{
  int exponente;
  float cociente;
} Termino;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, initialized the pointer before use it.

```
polinomio* polinomio_ = (polinomio*)malloc( sizeof(polinomio) );
termino* terminos = (termino*)malloc( sizeof(termino) * size );
```

Secondly, initialized polinomio_,

```
polinomio_->polinomio = terminos;
polinomio_->size - size;
```

At last, use it

```
scanf("%f",&(*(((*polinomio_).polinomio) + i ).cociente));
```

And I can't understand why not ->

```
scanf("%f",&(polinomio_->polinomio[i]->cociente));
```